# can it possible to split complex data format using hive sql

Tags: sql, split, hive, hiveql

Now,there is data like

```
a                                            b              c    
101:1.9|832:1.9|91:1.0|786:1.0|55:1.0|28:1.0 14:1.0|149:1.0 14:1.0|1:1.0
```

how can i get the results

```
a                       b       c
101;832;91;786;55;28    14;149  14;1
```

using hive sql . I am a newer to hive sql

Comment: What is between 28 and 14 and between 149 and 14? Are they different columns/rows?

Comment: Is it a single column or file ? And what is the rule for `$b` and '$c' ?

Comment: they are different columns, a, b, c

Comment: formatted input and output data according to your comment

Answer (score 0):

Using regexp_replace you can replace (everything after `:` till `|` or till the end of the string) with semicolon ;, then remove trailing semicolons.

Demo:

```
with mytable as(
select stack( 1, 
'101:1.9|832:1.9|91:1.0|786:1.0|55:1.0|28:1.0', 
'14:1.0|149:1.0','14:1.0|1:1.0' ) as (a, b, c)
  ) 
  
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(a, ':[0-9.]*(\\||$)','\073'),'\073$','') as a, 
       regexp_replace(regexp_replace(b, ':[0-9.]*(\\||$)','\073'),'\073$','') as b,
       regexp_replace(regexp_replace(c, ':[0-9.]*(\\||$)','\073'),'\073$','') as c
from mytable
```

Result:

```
a                       b       c
101;832;91;786;55;28    14;149  14;1
```